# Showing products only from selected category in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm trying to show products only from selected category but something goes wrong and I still can't understand what.

What I have done so far is I have added route in `routes.php`

```
Route::get('/admin/category/single/{categoryId}', ['uses' => 'AdminController@categoriesCheck']);
```

Then in AdminController I have added

```
public function categoriesCheck() {
    $products = Product::paginate(15);
    $categories = Categories::all();
    return View::make('site.admin.single_category', [
        'categories' => $categories,
        'product' => $products
    ]);
}
```

so 2 questions how if I click on category_id=1 how to make query to load only products where category_id=1 ( I have made column in product table which hold category_id for each product )
and how to make the view page?

currently I have dummy `single_category.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('title', 'Categories')

@section('content')

<div class="col-xs-12">
    <h3>Products List</h3>
    <hr />

    <div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $i => $product)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default text-center">
                <div class="panel-heading">{{{ $product['title'] }}}</div>
                <div class="panel-body min-h-230">
                    @if($product['image'])
                        <img class="max-150" src="{{ $product['image'] }}" alt="{{{ $product['title'] }}}" />
                        <br /><br />
                    @endif
                    {{ str_limit($product->description_small, 100) }}
                    @if (strlen($product->description_small) > 100)
                       <br/><br /> <a href="{{ URL::to('product/single/' . $product->product_id) }} " class="btn btn-info btn-block view-more">View More</a>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    @if(($i+1) % 3 == 0)
    </div><div class="row">
    @endif
    @endforeach
    </div>

    <hr />
    {{ $products->links() }}
</div>
@endsection
```

When I run the page now I got all products... no matter what category I click

Comment: You’re not filtering your products, you’re just paginating _all_ records.

Comment: Yes, that's what I can't understand.. how and where to build the query

Comment: Have you bothered to check the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)?

Comment: @MartinBean yes.. But I'm kinda new in whole frameworks and mvc model and still some stuffs are bit confusing and somehow complex.. like this case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First in your **Category** model you have to make the relationship with your **Products** so add this:

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Product');
}
```

Then in your controller you have to accept the category ID from the route and query a category by it:

```
public function categoriesCheck( $categoryId ) 
{
    $category = Categories::with('products')->findOrFail( $categoryId );
    return View::make('site.admin.single_category', [
        'category' => $category
    ]);
}
```

And finally in your view check if a category has products and if it has loop them:

```
@if($category->products->count())
    @foreach($category->products as  $product)
        //DIsplay product data
    @endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I just got this error and can't see from where `categories_id` came.. should be category_id...`Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'products.categories_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `products` where `products`.`categories_id` in (3))'`

Comment: Add a second parameter which is the foreign column name in the **Categories** model **products()** method `return $this->hasMany('Product', 'category_id');`.

Comment: So, it doesn't take automatically the `category_id` from Ctaegories model even when I have `protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';` there..

Comment: Great, glad I could help :)